# Customers arrive at a service center according to a Poisson process with a mean interarrival time of 15 minutes.

Tags: poisson-process, queueing-theory

Customers arrive at a service center according to a Poisson process with a mean inter-arrival time of 15 minutes.

1. What is the probability that no arrivals occur in the first half hour?
2. What is the expected time until the tenth arrival occurs?
3. What is the probability of more than five arrivals occurring in any half-hour period?
4. If two customers were observed to have arrived in the first hour, what is the probability that both arrived in the last 10 minutes of that hour?
5. If two customers were observed to have arrived in the first hour, what is the probability that at least one arrived in the last 10 minutes of that hour?

Comment: You should add your attempt in order to get answers otherwise it will be closed.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! In what context did you encounter the problem? What did you try? What do you think should be the approach to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

(a) mean interval = 15 minutes 
Hence 1/(15 min) = 60/15 = 4/hour 
T=1/2 hour 
f(x) = (e-(4/2)(4/2)^0)/0! = e-2 = 0.1353 
(b) P(x≤10) = Sum from x=0 to x=10 ((e-4(4)^x)/x!) = 0.997 
(c) P(x≤5) = Sum from x=0 to x=5 ((e-4(4)^x)/x!) = 0.785
    P(x>5) = 1 - 0.785 = 0.215